# How to get last year monday to friday weekly all data from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show Last year all weekly data. Like Monday to Friday all data. But I don't Understand how to write query. Please help me to solve the problem.

I will try this Query... But missing some day data.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename`
WHERE WEEKDAY(`EffectiveStartDate`) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
    AND WEEKDAY(`EffectiveEndDate`) BETWEEN 0 AND 4;
```

Comment: Please Explain your question with more details and code you have tried..

Comment: Pls follow the guidance set out in this topic on how to ask an sql related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: try change with 1 to 5  e.g  SELECT * FROM `tablename`
WHERE WEEKDAY(`EffectiveStartDate`) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
    AND WEEKDAY(`EffectiveEndDate`) BETWEEN 1 AND 5;

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  Date(date_column) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' 
       AND Weekday(date_column) IN ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```